# SQL select joined 2 tables same as one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL table `Authority` is:

```
AuthorNo  Price  PrePay(bit)
----------------------------
   1       250$    1
   2       120$    0
   3       300$    0
   4       112$    1
   5       25$     0
```

Table `Order` is:

```
AuthorNo  OrderNo
-----------------
  1         33
  1         34
  2         33
  2         38
  3         41
  3         82
  4         55
  4         21
  5         21
  5         66
```

I want the result is:

Select from `Authority.AuthorNo` where `AuthorNo` same in `Order.OrderNo` and at least one of the `AuthorNo.Prepay` is 1

```
AuthorNo
--------
   1
   2
   4
   5
```

How to select this?

Comment: `AuthorNo same as OrderNo in Order table also one of them AuthorNo Prepayed is 1` Can you somehow elaborate what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to find the authors that have orders that were also ordered by authors with PrePay?

Then you could use an `EXISTS` for this.

```
SELECT auth.AuthorNo
FROM Authority auth
JOIN [Order] ord ON ord.AuthorNo = auth.AuthorNo
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Order] ord_pp 
    JOIN Authority auth_pp 
      ON auth_pp.AuthorNo = ord_pp.AuthorNo 
     AND auth_pp.Prepay = 1
    WHERE ord_pp.OrderNo = ord.OrderNo
)
GROUP BY auth.AuthorNo;
```

A test [here](https://rextester.com/LVCX74533)

**Result:**

```
AuthorNo
--------
1
2
4
5
```

Comment: None of them will answer;
Attention : Both tables are in column `OrderNo` in `Order` table.

Comment: @MahdiYousef Updated, it works for the test that's included in the answer.

Comment: Solved,Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you just want to see the AuthorNo in the result? Try this

```
Select distinct a.AuthorNo
From Authority  a
join Order  b on a.AuthorNo=b.AuthorNo
where a.Prepay=1
```

Comment: you say authorNo = orderNo - how is that possible? Your order numbers have 2 digits and you author No has 1 digit. Can you clarify?

Comment: `AithorNo` samed by `OrderNo` in `Order` table.